# Storing address of char pointer in a char pointer in C

Tags: c

I am trying to achieve something in C and hope you guys can tell me where I went wrong.

So I have values that is an array of 6 const char pointers.

```
    int main() 
    {
      /* values is an array of 6 char pointers */
      const char *values[6] = 
       {
        "Two", 
        "Three", 
        "Four", 
        "Five", 
        "Six", 
        "Seven",
       };
       /* p is a pointer to a char pointer */     
       char *(*p) = &values[0];

    }
```

What I am doing here is to create p that is a pointer to a char pointer from my array and store the address of the first char pointer in my array into p.

Though the logic works, I keep getting a warning message saying:

**warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think its `values` not `value_names`

Comment: Fixed it, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can't cast a `const` pointer to non-`const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/const).

```
const char *(*p) = &values[0];
^~~~~
```

This is what you should have written.

Comment: Yup that fixed it! Thanks for the help. Will accept the answer in 10 mins